# How many sprints between 2 dates when the number of weeks cannot be exactly divided by sprint lenght?

Tags: scrum, sprint

I want to calculate  how many sprints I have between two dates, for example : April 1,2020 and June 4,2020.

The number of weeks between the two dates is : 9 weeks and 1 day. My Sprints are 2 weeks long.

Does this mean there are 4½ sprints between those 2 dates ?

I'd really appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: There's no such thing as a half sprint. If you have 9 weeks between the dates, you can fit at most 4 2-week sprints, maybe even less if you have an already established sprint cadence. For a newly started project, you may want to use the leftover time for pre-project team forming and initial backlog creation activities.

Comment: This is completely dependent on what you're doing with the data. Are you looking for how many sprints you can complete in this time block? Are you going to aggregate many of these time blocks in order to get a total (or average) sprint count? Are you trying to divine a sprint length based on a desired number of iterations over a given time block? The question you've asked here is not one of software engineering, it's one of figuring out what it is you actually want.

Answer (score 4):

There are no half-Sprints in Scrum.

The number of Sprints depends on your Sprint duration. If you had 1 week Sprints, you likely have Sprint Planning sessions on April 1, April 8, April 15, April 22, April 29, May 6, May 13, May 20, and May 27. You could also have 2 week Sprints starting on April 1, April 15, April 29, May 13, and May 27 (due to the fixed date, the final Increment would need to be delivered in less than 2 weeks). Or you could have 3 week Sprints on April 1, April 22, May 6, and May 27 (again - a final Increment would be delivered in less than 3 weeks after starting the Sprint). You could also have 4 week Sprints on April 1, April 29, May 27 (again - less than every other Sprint). Or even month long Sprints starting on April 1, May 1, and June 1.

For the Sprints that are less than the other Sprints, you have some options. You could either target a delivery earlier than the end of the effort. You would simply not do any work after the last full Sprint's review and perhaps work exclusively on transition efforts or disband early. The other option would be to plan a Sprint at less than full capacity, ending on with a Sprint Review on June 4.

And this is only considering full-week Sprints. Nothing says that a Sprint needs to be 1 week long or longer. The only rule about the length of a Sprint in Scrum is that a Sprint must be 1 month or less in duration.